# Prevent Access to Website to all but allow server cron

Tags: cron

Okay I searched and I can't find the solution.

I have a folder on my website where I'm keeping some script I use for something. My server via Cron job has to access this folder all the time. But if someone goes to the URL of the folder they can see the Index page, and I would like to prevent it. I want it to throw up a 403 or a 404 or a 500 or any page, I don't care what it is.

I tried this in htaccess:

**deny from all**

But this also blocks my own server and breaks the Cron job. I tried a few other solutions I found here and there, but they didn't work.

One of the things I saw is you can block everyone but allow your server access via IP. But I'm on Hostgator Shared hosting, and so my IP isn't static (as far as I know). I don't want to have to worry that at any time my server's IP may change and break my Cron thing.

Isn't there a nice elegant simple and permanent solution for this? Block access to the folder to all people, allow my own server/cron to access it at will.

Thank you :)

Comment: How does your cron job "access" this folder?

Comment: In cPanel I create a Cron job, and I use a link like this in the Command - curl 'https://example.com/MYFOLDER/MYFILE.php' - I hope that explains it. I can't say I understand the mechanisms behind it.

Comment: Are we talking about a single computer or two? That is, is the cron job running on the same machine as the web server?

Comment: The cron job is set on my Hostgator hosting. The cron job runs on its own. The cron job runs on my Hostgator hosting, and my files are located on my Hostgator hosting (cPanel, Cron Job, File Manager, etc). The computer has nothing to do with it. I can log into my hosting from any computer and it doesn't make a difference. Sorry, I'm kind of a noob with all this, maybe I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: I'm going to assume this is all a single computer (a "hostgator" server, whatever that is). In which case, why not curl http://127.0.0.1/stuff and allow access from 127.0.0.1? Or why is curl/http involved in the first place? Can't you run php directly?

Comment: Hostgator is a company that offers hosting services. I host my websites on it :) I didn't know I can define the curl like that. So how would I write it exactly? - 127.0.0.1/curl 'example.com/MYFOLDER/MYFILE.php' - that's probably wrong. And curl is involved because when I tried doing it with " php ... " it wouldn't work. It wouldn't find the location I think. Only curl worked.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming, making it off-topic on StackOverflow. Also, if you don't know what an IP address is, you probably shouldn't be hosting your own website.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you want to call a script which is stored on the same server.
You don't need to use curl for it, you can just run the script by providing it's path and the php installation.

You can prevent outside access to the script if you just don't save the script in your public_html directory.

Your cronjob command will something look like this:

```
/opt/php70/bin/php /home/<USERNAME>/cron.php
```

The exact directory structure differs depending on your webhost.